# Get result for all dates within a given range including non-existent dates

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

(UPDATED)
I have two tables like below

Table `subscribers`:

```
id | service_id | subscribe_date

1  | 1          | 2016-08-10
2  | 2          | 2016-08-09
3  | 2          | 2016-08-05
4  | 1          | 2016-08-03
```

Table `services`:

```
id | service_name

1  | test1          
2  | test2  
3  | test2
```

`subscribers.service_id` has a foreign key on `services.id`

I want to get a data from this tables like below :

```
service_id | subscribe_date | count

1        | 2016-08-10       | 1  
1        | 2016-08-09       | 0
2        | 2016-08-10       | 0  
2        | 2016-08-09       | 1
3        | 2016-08-10       | 0  
3        | 2016-08-09       | 0
```

I trying to get this data with below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), subscribe_date, service_id
FROM subscribers
    INNER JOIN services ON subscribers.service_id = services.id
WHERE subscribe_date BETWEEN '2016-08-09' AND '2016-08-10'
GROUP BY service_id, subscribe_date;
```

But I am not successful. I get the below result:

```
1        | 2016-08-10       | 1  
2        | 2016-08-09       | 1
```

Comment: Could you please explain the expected output?

Comment: output should be show each service subscriptions count in special date that is in where cause

Comment: It won't be possible unless you take help from a `calendar` table. But doing this will definitely aggravate the beauty of your code. Better do this in application level.

Comment: @1000111, can't OP use subscribe_date as calendar table?

Comment: I don't think so. `Calendar` table is supposed to provide all the dates within a given range. Since `subscribe_date`s are scattered so that `calendar` table is needed. If `subscribe_date`s weren't scattered then we don't need the calendar table actually :p. @jarlh

Comment: @1000111, yes, you're probably right. (Bad choice of sample data made me jump to conclusions...)

Comment: @1000111 can you please post your answer with tables structure and queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Since you don't have any `calendar` table so that we need to created all the dates between your given date range (inclusive) through a query. But like I said you need to agree on the [terms & conditions](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23063743/) of this query before using it.

```
SELECT 
dateWiseServices.id AS service_id,
dateWiseServices.`Day` AS subscribed_date,
COALESCE(yourQuery.total,0) AS cnt

FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    S.id,
    dateTable.Day
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT ADDDATE('2016-08-09', INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS DAY
    FROM (
    SELECT a.a
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
    ) a
    JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
    WHERE 
    @i < DATEDIFF('2016-08-10', '2016-08-09')
    ) AS dateTable
    CROSS JOIN Services S
) AS dateWiseServices

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, subscribe_date, service_id
    FROM subscribers
            INNER JOIN services ON subscribers.service_id = services.id
    WHERE subscribe_date BETWEEN '2016-08-09' AND '2016-08-10'
    GROUP BY service_id, subscribe_date
) AS yourQuery 
ON dateWiseServices.id = yourQuery.service_id AND dateWiseServices.`Day` = yourQuery.subscribe_date
ORDER BY dateWiseServices.id, dateWiseServices.`Day` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Just to learn , how should i do this if i have calendar table?

Comment: The full answer would be too broad! :) I would suggest to post it as a separate question.

Comment: How can i we have a chat? is this possible?

Comment: You can leave a comment here

Comment: I just want to know how can i use this query when i have calendar table, can you please post the answer in the comment

Comment: How the query would look like can be found in this [**link**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23063885/). But like I said, it would be a broad answer that how would you introduce a calendar table and later how to keep it up to date.

Comment: Your post was very helpful, thanks :) it's working like charm

Answer (score 0):

Instead inner join use left join

```
SELECT COUNT(*), subscribe_date, service_id 
FROM subscribers LEFT JOIN services ON subscribers.service_id = services.id 
GROUP BY service_id,subscribe_date;
```

Comment: OP wants to add rows with count 0. LEFT JOIN wont help.

Comment: Thanks but it wasn't helpful

Answer (score 0):

Please try this I hope this will help you..

```
SELECT service_id,subscribe_date,COUNT(service_id)
FROM subscribers WHERE subscribe_date BETWEEN '2016-08-09' AND '2016-08-10'
GROUP BY service_id, subscribe_date;
```

In case you trying to check foreign key also try below query.

```
SELECT subscribers.service_id,subscribers.subscribe_date,COUNT(subscribers.service_id)
FROM subscribers,services WHERE subscribers.service_id=services.id 
AND subscribe_date BETWEEN '2016-08-09' AND '2016-08-10' GROUP BY service_id, subscribe_date;
```